# Cannot delete LWC: Validation_LWCDefinition

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to delete a LWC from my sandbox that is no longer needed and isn't referenced anywhere else.  When I delete it, I'm getting this error message:

Unable to Complete the Requested Change
Your changes could not be completed for the following reasons:

Reason: Validation_LWCDefinition

Section: ReferencedBy

What does this message mean?  How do I resolve the issue?

[image]

Comment: Did you try deleting from Dev Console or an IDE?

Comment: You can't delete an LWC component from Dev Console that I know of.

Comment: The following CLI command returns the same error:  sfdx force:source:delete -m LightningComponentBundle:rsCancelTransferDetails

Comment: You can delete it from Dev Console too.  Here is how https://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/delete-lightning-component-in-salesforce/ but I guess you will hit same error

Comment: Next logical step do you mind sharing code for this LWC to make sure it has no dependency. You might want to check dependencies section to see if any

Comment: The component does reference an Apex class, but I wouldn't think that would prevent the component from being deleted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137394/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-michael-sobczak).

Answer (score 2):

We were having the same error message while trying to delete a lightning web component. To solve this issue from the VS Code, I've removed all `targets` and `targetConfigs` and tried to deploy the component. Doing that we were able to get the correct reference error, which was a flow version reference in our case. After deleting the flow version we were able to delete the component.